# Set background colour of selected tabBarItem

Tags: ios, objective-c

My question not obvious that it may look like, i want to change colour of rectangle view, that contain selected tab bar item. Not tint or tabBar colour, but colour of whole view (tab bar item). Similar topic only suggest to change tint colour. I have 5 tab bar items and, when user switch between tabs, selected tab become red, for example. So, there always should be 1 red tab bar item and 4 blue.

I guess i can draw 10 different images for those tab bar items, and ask tabBarController to set different image for each one tab bar item, but i really hope that there is much simpler solution.

I have read through Apple guidance about tabBar, and sadly there is no way to change colour of specific (selected) item. Or maybe i skip something? You can find this guide if you interested following this link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UITabBar.html

How could i set colour for selected item? Any advice would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: AFAIK, using images as the docs suggest is the only way to achieve what you're trying to do.

Comment: It is solution, but kind a tedious (especially making universal app, for iPhone and iPad)

Comment: I'd think anything else you'd try to do with code would be more tedious and messier. Good luck.